# How to set class properties that are dependent on other properties when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a class with a structure similar to this

```
public class TestClass1 
{ 
    public TestClass1() 
    {
    }

    private string _name;

    public string ScriptName { get; set; }

    public string Name {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            ScriptName = a_baseProp1.Substring(0,4);
        }
    }

    public string a_baseProp1 { get; set; }
    public string a_baseProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to Deserialize the following json

`{ Name: "abcdefgh", a_baseProp1: "a_baseProp1", a_baseProp2: "a_baseProp2" }`

with Newtonsoft deserializer

`TestClass1 tc1 = (TestClass1)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(jObj), typeof(TestClass1));`

I'm getting this error:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' TestClass1.a_baseProp1.get returned null.`

I don't understand why a_baseProp1 is null when it's trying to set a ScriptName. I tried using JsonProperty Order attributes, hoping that by the time Name property is processed, the other class properties would already be in place, but that didn't help.

I can't modify the existing class properties setters and getters as they are used by another project.

Is there a way around this?

### Response to proposed duplicate

The question is about reading deserialized object property values when deserialization process is in flight. The suggested duplicate question has nothing to say about this.

Comment: That class is extremely wierd. You are completely ignoring the `value` being passed in when setting the property, and the getter is recursive so will throw a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @DavidG, my bad sorry. The sample code has now been updated

Comment: OK, still weird that `ScriptName` is set when you set `Name`. But what is happening, is when you set `Name`, `a_baseProp1` is null so you cannot do `.Substring` on it without getting the null ref exception.

Comment: either use read-only properties where you do `public string ScriptName => _name..Substring(0,4)`, or if you don't need that value serialized, just add `GetScriptName` method

Comment: @DavidG, that I understand. Is there a way to make deserializer use the value of `a_baseProp1` from the json instead of reading it as null. Like I said I tried using JSONPropertyOrder, but to no avail.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek sorry can you elaborate please. It's not about getting the ScriptName value or serializing it. It's about setting its value when the deserialization happens

Comment: `JsonProperty(Order = ...)` is only used for serialisation, not deserialisation. You really should look at changing the setters here. Perhaps you can set `ScriptName` only when `a_baseProp1` is set, or don't set `ScriptName` and make it always calculated from the `a_baseProp1` property.

Comment: @DavidG, thanks. So am I right to assume that when deserialization process is in flight, it's not possible to access deserialized object properties until the process has completed?

Comment: The only way to control that would be to create a constructor that you could manually decide how to initialise everything.

Comment: For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uYM1CP

Comment: The most likely problem is that the properties are not set all at once, so the deserializer sets the `Name` property, which then tries to get the substring of `a_baseProp1` which has not been set yet.